# Get a handle of Contact being saved

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on my first  small OutLook Addin and I need to get the event of the ContactItem being saved or that was saved to then send it off to an external API. How can I get a hold of that event in Outlook Add in?.

Would that be tapping into the `ActiveExplorer SelectionChange` event?, not sure how to approach this.

EDIT: Also, what is the ContactItem for Display as?, i can't seem to find it, I found notes was Body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use ContactItem.Write event, but that requires you to track which contact was selected and opened, or you can use Items.ItemAdd/ItemChange events on the MAPIFolder.Items collection, where MAPIFolder points to the folder returned by Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).

Comment: Do you happen to know what the property is for "Display as" in ContactItem?

Comment: ContactItem.FileAs - take a look at a contact with OutlookSpy(http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - it will show the data both on Outlook Object Model and Extended MAPI level.